# How to find which voltage a solenoid would operate in

Tags: solenoid

What is solenoid used in [Orbit 91213 water timer](https://www.orbitonline.com/products/sprinkler-systems/timers/timers/hose-faucet-timers-1-dial-1-outlet-digital-timer/1-dial-hose-faucet-timer-1960/91213)? I have one which lasted quite some time, but lately some issue in its circuit made the display useless, but I think solenoid would be intact.

What instruments would I need to find this out?

Comment: Not entirely sure you want to use what they're using. Looking at the reviews this product has should tell you the reliability of the product. The operating voltage is usually specified by the manufacturer of the solenoid valve. As far as finding what solenoid valve is used here is more than likely proprietary.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171169/how-can-i-trigger-this-watering-timer-manually?rq=1

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/en/maker/projects/teardown-automatic-garden-timer/12d2b38e2a1348ecbfa0e976d5a4915b

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is always going to be to check the manufacturer's datasheet. Look for a part number and do some googling.

If the part number is scratched out or otherwise unsearchable, the next best answer would be using an LCR meter to check the inductance and impedance then find a datasheet for equipment with similar specs. If you don't have an LCR meter, a multimeter to check the coil resistance is a good start.

Failing all that, and assuming a full reverse engineering isn't on the table, there's always trial and error. It's as good as garbage anyway if you can't figure it out, right?

The device is powered by 2 AA batteries. I'd begin testing with native voltages. Start with 1.5V, then 3V. Work your way up slowly with an adjustable power supply if those don't work. A reverse biased diode in parallel (flyback diode) to snub inductive voltage spikes would be a good idea too if you care about your power source.